# My graphics card disabled my BIOS

Tags: graphics-card, bios

I want to access my BIOS without taking out my GeForce GTX 970 graphics card. My 970 disables my BIOS and so I would need to take out my graphics card to get around it. Is there another solution that doesn't require me to take out my 970? I want to enable Intel VT-x (which is supported with my processor) for virtualization.

Comment: What card exactly is it? I've never heard of something like this happening. Did you have to enable an option to disable BIOS?

Comment: It is not possible for your card to disable your BIOS.  Something else is going on.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @TimmyJim It's a Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme COre Edition.

Comment: @Ramhound I recently reset my PC. After doing a fresh install, I could not access my BIOS because my graphics card was inside. I took it out and it worked perfectly.

Comment: That just means the card is preventing your system from being able to POST.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, is there a way to allow my PC to POST?

Comment: So the PC is indeed not booting with the card.  Do you mean all other hardware requirements for the card?

Comment: @Ramhound My PC works absolutely normal with the graphics card. It is just when it is installed, that is when I cannot access my BIOS. It will fully boot up, I just cannot hold any buttons while on start-up to access any of those menus. My hardware requirements/power supply meet the requirements for the graphics card.

Comment: CamouflougedCow - I have seen this before when the there's a conflict with the graphics card on the card not playing well with the built-in graphics card on the motherboard. The solution I believe was to disable built-in graphics card in BIOS where you can enable that and then plug in the card and if I recall correctly, that resolved in the cases where this has been applicable in instances I've seen occur. I will gladly add as an answer if you want me to and it works but that's what I'd try next. The make and model of the PC may be helpful too. I think Intel and AMD based mixed causes issue.

Comment: If you cannot disable built-in graphics card see if there's an option to change the default perhaps but if you tell me the make and model of the PC you have this card in, I can find more detail on the BIOS options potentially.

Comment: The BIOS might be too old to handle this video card. Let us know your computer model and BIOS version (displayed when booting), to check if a newer BIOS exists. Check also if [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/42isuq/troubleshootingnew_pc_wont_boot_when_gtx_970_card/) applies to your BIOS.

Comment: Mr. CamouflougedCow - Please provide an update when you get a chance and let us know if you have an update or tried anything. Did you find my comment of any usefulness? How about any of the answers already provided? Your bounty ends tomorrow so I thought I'd ask you since I don't see an update from you since 8/28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer's BIOS might be too old to handle this video card. Let us know your computer model and operating system, as well as the BIOS version
(displayed when booting), to check if a newer BIOS exists
(and to give better answers).
Ensure also that your chipset driver is up to date.

The post [New PC won't boot when GTX 970 card is installed](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/42isuq/troubleshootingnew_pc_wont_boot_when_gtx_970_card/) has
this solution which might (or not) apply to your BIOS :

> I changed 2 settings in the BIOS and the next time I installed the
>   card everything started up great. First I changed "PCI Express Slot
>   and M.2 Bandwidth" from "PCIe Express 1 and 2 slot at X1 Mode" to "M.2
>   Mode". This probably made the difference. I also randomly changed POST
>   delay from 3 to 5 but that sounds less likely to have fixed the
>   problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Video Priorities in the BIOS. Set PCIE on top and then plug in your Graphics Card again.
2. Update your Graphics Card BIOS, if possible

Pretty sure that only the priority list is in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with some poorly written BIOSes.  Likely what is happening is that the BIOS is posting all of its diagnostic messages to the onboard video, but you don't see them because nothing is plugged in there.  Then, when Windows loads the driver for the video card, everything comes up normally.

What you can do in this situation is connect one of your screen's inputs to the onboard video.  Most monitors have multiple inputs on them (say, one HDMI and one DVI port).  Whenever you need to go into your BIOS just switch the screen to that input and reboot.  It should still respond to <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or whatever your BIOS key is.  You just wouldn't see anything unless you're looking at the onboard video's output and not your video card.

Unfortunately there's nothing you can really do about this unless there is a setting in your BIOS that controls it.